# FireFox seems to be remembering my old image map

Tags: jquery, firefox, dictionary

I have a chart control on my page which has the ability to 'drill down.' I use image maps to delineate possible drill points. All of this code works perfectly fine under latest Chrome and latest Internet Explorer.

[image]

So, looking at the above image, on the left in the console you see three entries.

- Entry 1: When the Chart first loads on the page, this is its initial image map.
- Entry 2: When the Chart is drilled upon, this is the next level's image map -- this map renders correctly.
- Entry 3: Undoing the drill down. Note the data is identical to that of the first entry.

My right monitor is currently displaying Entry 3's chart, and inspecting the HTML markup I see that Entry 3's map has been loaded.

Yet, if you look in the lower left hand corner of my right monitor, you see javascript:DrillChart('1489'). This method is part of Entry 2 -- NOT entry 1/3.

```
function UndoDrillDown() {
    $('#ChartLoading').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: '../Chart/UndoDrillDown',
        data: { ReportID: reportID },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: Reload
    });
}

function Reload(htmlImageMap) {
    //Remove the old image map and then add a fresh one.
    console.log(htmlImageMap);
    //$('#HistoricalChartDialog').children("map").remove();
    $('#HistoricalChartMap').remove();
    $(htmlImageMap).appendTo('#HistoricalChartDialog');

    //Fetch image associated with new image imap.
    var reportID = parseInt($('#ReportSelector').val());

    $('#HistoricalChart').bind('load', function () {
        $(this).unbind('load');
        //When drilling down it does not make sense to continue showing the old tooltip after clicking.
        $('#CustomTooltip').hide();
        $('#ChartLoading').hide();
        $(this).show();
    }).bind('error', function () {
        $(this).unbind('error');
        $('#ChartLoading').hide();
        $('#ChartLoadingError').show();
    }).attr('src', '../Chart/HistoricalChart?ReportID=' + reportID + '&cacheBuster=' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

I have tried removing my image map in multiple different ways. As far as I can tell the image map has been removed, but FireFox still remembers the old data.

EDIT: If I hide HistoricalChart before showing it again then it works properly in FireFox... I'd like to avoid the flicker if possible, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694503 but that's fixed in Firefox 10.  What Firefox version are you running?

If you do need to work around it in old Firefox versions, removing all the `<area>` elements from the `<map>` before removing the `<map>` would also work.

Comment: Good call. My version of FireFox was out of date -- I was on 7. Not sure why the autoupdater didn't run. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird quirk in FireFox. I figured out a solution, but curious why I need to use it:

```
function Reload(htmlImageMap) {
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        //Image maps are 'held onto' in FireFox even when the HTML is removed.
        $('#HistoricalChart').attr('usemap', '');
    }

    //Remove the old image map and then add a fresh one.
    $('#HistoricalChartDialog').children("map").remove();
    $(htmlImageMap).appendTo('#HistoricalChartDialog');

    $('#HistoricalChart').attr('usemap', '#HistoricalChartMap');

    //Fetch image associated with new image imap.
    var reportID = parseInt($('#ReportSelector').val());

    $('#HistoricalChart').bind('load', function () {
        $(this).unbind('load');
        //When drilling down it does not make sense to continue showing the old tooltip after clicking.
        $('#CustomTooltip').hide();
        $('#ChartLoading').hide();
        $(this).show();
    }).bind('error', function () {
        $(this).unbind('error');
        $('#ChartLoading').hide();
        $('#ChartLoadingError').show();
    }).attr('src', '../Chart/HistoricalChart?ReportID=' + reportID + '&cacheBuster=' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing from cache? If not press Ctrl then F5 and it must refresh and show the latest changes.

Comment: If I call hide on HistoricalChart at the start of Reload then the proper image map is loaded. Seems to be  quite the quirk. Perhaps it is a cache issue, but the chart has a cache buster on it -- not sure how I could add one to the image map.